# How to set selected value of dynamic drop down using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list which is dynamically generated using ajax on page load.
On the other hand I have a php variable which contains the value to be selected by default.
However, when Iam trying to do this it isn't selecting the value. Following is code:

HTML & PHP

```
<h1>Venue: Edit</h1>
<a href="/venue"><< Back to Venue List</a>
<br />
<form method="post" id="venueEdit" action="<?php echo URL;?>venue/editSave/<?php echo $this->venue['id']; ?>">
    <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="cvenue" class="main">Venue</label>
                <input id="cvenue" class="required" type="text" name="venue" value="<?php echo $this->venue['name']; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="ccity" class="main">City</label>
                <input id="ccity" class="required" type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->venue['city']; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="ccountry" class="main">Country</label>
                    <select id="ccountry" class="required" name="country">
                        <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
                    </select>

            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="main">&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>   
</form>
```

JS:

```
function populateCountryDropDown(url){
    $.get(url, function(o) {
        for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
            $('select[name="country"]').append('<option value="' + o[i].id + '">' + o[i].name + "</option>");
        }
    }, 'json');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        populateCountryDropDown('<?php echo URL; ?>' + 'country/xhrGetCountryList');
        $('select[name="country"]').val('<?php echo $this->venue['countryid']; ?>');
        $("#venueEdit").validate();
    });
```

I tried to alert the php value and it's ok but if I alert the select option value it's always null as at that point it's still populating the drop down list. I don't know how to solve this. Would appreciate your guys help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your code to set the value into the callback, to trigger the value being set *after* the AJAX call fired off by `$.get()` returns.

```
function populateCountryDropDown(url){
    $.get(url, function(o) {
        for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
            $('select[name="country"]').append('<option value="' + o[i].id + '">' + o[i].name + "</option>");
        }
        $('select[name="country"]').val('<?php echo $this->venue['countryid']; ?>');
        $("#venueEdit").validate();
    }, 'json');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        populateCountryDropDown('<?php echo URL; ?>' + 'country/xhrGetCountryList');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This code here:

```
$('select[name="country"]').val('<?php echo $this->venue['countryid']; ?>');
```

Try changing to:

```
$('select[name="country"]').val('<?php echo $this->venue["countryid"]; ?>');  // Double quotes around countryid vs the single quote.
```

Comment: Double versus single quotes make no difference for what the OP is doing in PHP.

Comment: ^^ exactly.  Makes no difference at all.